# How to configure Qos Dsl-2750U?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, gaming, qos

my internet is so slow when family starts using it along with me , i get crazy **lags** in-game (league of legends) & browsing aswell (even facebook) , but when i'm alone on the network (which rarely happens) everything works smoothly ,

The router is Dlink dsl-2750U

i'm using a laptop wich only supports wifi

**Queue page (CAR Scheduling Strategy)**

[image: queue]

**Queue page (SP Scheduling Strategy)**

[image]

**Queue page (WRR Scheduling Strategy)**

[image]

**Classification page (i tried & didn't seem to work)**

[image]

**Dhcp ip range**

[image]

Could someone help me setup Qos , to give my laptop priority in games & browsing (overall priority)
& i'm using my laptop on wifi , it only supports wifi
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've given a textbook description of the major symptoms of a well-known design flaw in modems/routers/gateways/APs, known as bufferbloat. It's very common, especially on DSL. The obsolete scheduling strategies your D-Link supports won't help. Prioritizing your gaming traffic over other traffic just shovels the problem into someone else's lap, and even that might not be enough to make your gaming lag go away.

The true solution to bufferbloat is modern "Smart Queue Managment" (SQM) using algorithms like "Cake" or "FQ-CoDel". Most routers' factory firmware is way behind the times on this, so you have to load your own open source Linux firmware on the router (such as OpenWrt or DD-WRT or Tomato, etc. etc.) to get Cake or FQ-CoDel support.

https://www.stoplagging.com/ can help walk you through your options for fixing your bufferbloat problem.

Comment: Wow Thank you , finally man , i thought that after watching too many vids & reading articles i gave up to fix it on my own , you given me hope that there's an option & my router sucks, i started to get depressed over this lol , imma give a try , thank you i'll update you with it :D

Comment: oh man , i was getting pumped , there is no firmware compatible with my router :'(
what should i do ?  , neither Openwrt /Dd-Wrt or Tomato supports my router (dsl-2750U)

Comment: If I were you I'd try to see if there's a way to turn the DSL-2750U into just a transparent bridging DSL modem (turn off its DHCP, NAT, router/gateway/firewall, and Wi-Fi features), and then buy an IQRouter from evenroute.com. It's a turn-key solution.